# React Native CarPlay - PointOfInterest Template

Tags: ios, react-native, carplay

How to use PointOfInterest Template in react native. While integrating app getting crash.

example: react-native-carplay : 2.3.0

```
const template = new PointOfInterestTemplate({
    title: 'Example',
    items: [
        {
            id: 'test',
            location: { latitude: 64.011, longitude: -21.66 },
            title: 'Testing',
            subtitle: 'foobar',
        },
    ],
});
CarPlay.pushTemplate(template, false);
```